# UIView Resize with handles

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I would like to make a `UIView` be user movable and resizable.  It should have "handles" on each corner so that the user can resize it.

(Camera+ has this sort of feature, but they use it to Crop.)

Does a library or class exist for this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one you can use:
http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/spuserresizableview